# Pkg not defined

Tags: plot, julia

I tried following the [official Julia docs](https://julialang.org/downloads/plotting.html) on plotting, where the following code is proposed for plotting:

```
Pkg.add("PyPlot")
using PyPlot
x = range(0,stop=2*pi,length=1000); y = sin.(3*x + 4*cos.(2*x))
plot(x, y, color="red", linewidth=2.0, linestyle="--")
```

Julia v1.0.2 exits with the error

```
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: Pkg not defined
```

My question is how to actually run the above code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `Pkg` module is not loaded, because this seems to be deprecated. To fix this the following line has to be added before the first line

```
using Pkg
```

The code then works for me not from the command line interface, but within an interactive julia session and produces the following image:

[image: Plot]

Comment: As noted the package manager is not loaded by default anymore. I have submitted a PR to update the examples: https://github.com/JuliaLang/www.julialang.org/pull/244

Comment: To add, in the REPL you can press the `]` key to get the `Pkg` REPL-mode, then type `add PyPlot`.